# Count from other table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I am having problem to count number of devices where `guid` is not null.

It need to get all the shops by user `user_id` and then count all the devices where `guid` is not null.

```
$shops = Shop::with('devices')->where('user_id', $userId)->get();

$deviceActive = $shops->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
     return $carry + $item->devices->whereNotNull('guid')->count();
});

dd($deviceActive );
```

It work when I do:

```
return $carry + $item->devices->count();
```

but it need to count where `guid` is not null.

I would also be interested to hear if there is alternative `reduce` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$item->devices` is a collection there is no `whereNotNull()` for collections. So try to use [`where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where):

```
$item->devices->where('guid', '<>', null)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$shops = Shop::with('devices')
->where('user_id', $userId)
->where('guid', '!=', null)->get();

$get_count = count($shops); // it return how many values have $shops
```

OR

```
$shops= DB::table('devices')->where('user_id', $userId)
    ->where('guid', '!=', null)->get();

$get_count = count($shops);
```

if you did not have the class DB add at your controller:

```
use DB;
```

Comment: That will return number of shops, not devices.